# UITableViewCell height from initial size to full screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

how i can swipe down (scroll) one cell from my `tableviewcell` (static cells) and make this cell fullscreen?

[image]

I know how make the cell full height:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.frame.size.height;
}
```

But how i can start this cell with a fixed height and after swipe down (scroll) the cell, make the cell fullscreen?

Thank you

Comment: Describe "slide down." Scroll?

Comment: To me it is not clear what you want to achieve. BTW, heightForRowAtIndexPath is called every time when a cell becomes visible or when the data is reloaded (reloadData mehtod on UITableView).

Comment: i added an image to illustrate better

Comment: So you want a downswipe that starts in your map cell to expand the cell, not scroll the table, right?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this sort of thing is actually to treat this as a master-detail interface. The gesture does not *really* expand the cell; it does a "push" of another view controller containing the full-screen version. And it does it with a *custom transition animation*, so that it *looks* like the cell is expanding to form the full-screen version.

And the same thing when returning (popping), in reverse.

This is an example; it isn't 100% identical to what you're doing, but it shows how the push-plus-custom-animation can give the sort of effect you're after:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also monitor frame changes in your cell class and expand when the cell is pressed, (not scroll if that's what you really want) and by monitoring frame change you can expand the cells height. Let me know if you want more information because this is on selection, not on scroll.